# How to setState of this nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi Im having troubles setting the state when I press a button 'Send' on one email input.

I'm trying it avoiding mutation as React docs recommends.

My state properties are this:

```
state = {
    emailForm: {
      email: {
        elementType: 'email-invitation-input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'email',
          placeholder: 'Enter an email..',
        },
        value: '',
        valid: true,
        required: true
      }
    },
    requestStatus : false,
    validationMessage : null,
    formIsValid: false,
  }
```

So I tried three ways to set empty value to my email input trough the state but no one worked :(

**First try:**
I used ES6 spread operator to change it value but it doesn't change the input value:

```
 this.setState({
   email: {
           ...this.state.emailForm.email,
           value: '',
           },
 });

 this.setState({
   email: Object.assign({}, this.state.emailForm.email, {
     value: '',
   }),
 });
```

Another try using `immutability-helper` package

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
let newData = { email: {
   ...this.state.emailForm.email,
   value: '',
 }, };

 this.setState({
   email: update(this.state.newData, {
     value: {$set: newData},
   })
 });
```

**Second try:**
I used Ramda.js but it neither works.

```
setObjectByPath(fieldPath, value) {
  this.setState({
    emailForm: R.set(R.lensPath(fieldPath), value, this.state.emailForm)
  })
}

setObjectByPath(this.state.emailForm.email,'');
```

**Third try:**

I used `react-addons-update`:

```
import update from 'react-addons-update';

this.setState({
  email: update(this.state.newData, {
    value: {$set: newData},
  })
 });
```

All tries does nothing or it creates a new email input with empty value below.

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  emailForm: {
    email: {
      ...prevState.emailForm.email,
      value: ''
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but I keep the doubt on how to use that packages to set my state, anyway thanks bro !